# Question on transformation law of spinors and the law $\xi^{\mu '} = D(L)^{\mu '}_{\nu}\xi^{\nu}$ where $D(L)$ is a representation of Lorentz group

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, group-theory, representation-theory, spinors

In the reference $[1]$, the author presents the tensor quantities via its transformation laws. I'm pretty confortable with Pseudo-Riemannian geometry and tensors. But, when group theory enters the game, I can become a bit confused.

Firstly, some notation: $L^{\uparrow}_{+}$ is the proper orthocronos lorentz group; $L \in L^{\uparrow}_{+}$ is a matrix of this group (or even in component form $L^{\mu ' }\hspace{0.1mm}_{\nu}$); $D(L)$ is a representation of the Lorentz group; $S(L)$ is the spin representation of Lorentz group.

Now, in $[1]$ we have the definitions of:

> $$V^{\mu '}(x^{\alpha'}) = L^{\mu ' }\hspace{0.1mm}_{\nu}V^{\nu}(x^{\alpha})\tag{1}$$
>
> $$\xi^{\mu '}(x^{\alpha'}) = D(L)^{\mu ' }\hspace{0.1mm}_{\nu}\xi^{\nu}(x^{\alpha})\tag{2}$$
>
> $$\psi^{\mu '}(x^{\alpha'}) = S(L)^{\mu ' }\hspace{0.1mm}_{\nu}\psi^{\nu}(x^{\alpha})\tag{3}$$

#### Discussion

So in $(1)$, I can understand perfectly, they are vectors (and generaly tensors). I simply don't understand why we would choose to create a new kind of object like in $(2)$, I don't even know what are their names under that general transformation law. And I don't know if $(1)$ is a particular case of $(2)$; I do know that $(3)$  is a particular case of $(2)$. Also, these transformations are for Lorentz group and propably $(3)$ are the Dirac spinors. I'm wondering if when we use a spin representation of Galileo group, $G \in \mathrm{Gal}$, we would recover the *Pauli spinors* under $\Psi^{i '}(x^{k'}) = S(G)^{i ' }\hspace{0.1mm}_{j}\Psi^{j}(x^{k})$.

#### Question

**Are the objects in $(2)$ just vectors that lies in vector spaces differently from $(1)$?**

---

$[1]$ A.O. BARUT. "Electrodynamics and Classical Theory of Fields aand Particles". pg $37$.

Answer (score 0):

So I think generally this notation is a bit confusing. You said you are not too sure about what happens when groups enter the picture so let me recap slightly:

What we are working with here are Lie-groups. These are groups that also admit a smooth manifold structure. As such we can e.g. define tangentspaces and derivations on these groups. However I actually think that it is secondary to your question what Lie groups are so I wont go into detail. (Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Representations: An Elementary Introduction By Brian C. Hall is the standard reference if you want to read into it).

More interesting is the concept of a representation of a group. The idea here is that generally a group just consists of a collection of elements satisfying certain properties however in physics (and in many areas of mathematics as well) it is interesting what these groups do to different elements. E.g. the rotation group (in 3-d) can be defined abstractly as all vectors on the solid radius $\pi$ sphere with antipodal points identified together with a multiplication map on such vectors.

This definition is lovely for understanding properties of the group however intutively the group (for a physicist) is defined by how its elements act on vectors: It rotates them by a certain angle around a certain axis. However what if we instead want to know how it acts on points or extended objects? Or objects living in higher or lower dimensional vectorspaces? Or what if we want to specify that rotations should only affect certain objects but leave others invariant? (e.g. if we look at moving charged and uncharged particles (all of unit mass) in a magentic field from the center of mass frame, the charged particles will follow circular paths while the non charged will be unaffected by the magnetic field. We might model this with a rotation applied to the chraged particles but this rotation not acting on the uncharged particles.)

We can capture these ideas and solve these problems with the notion of a representation of a group. For this we will think of the group $G$ as some abstract object encoding the fundamental concept of e.g Rotations, while a representation will be what tells us how this concept acts on objects.

More rigorous, in the case of matrix lie groups, a representation is a (smooth) group homomorphism from $G \rightarrow Gl(V)$ under which $g \mapsto \Pi(g)$. Here $V$ is the vectorspace of objects we want out group to act on, and the map essentially defines what the action of the group on these objects is. Imporantly the group homomorphism ensures that our group is mapped to a (Lie) subgroup of $GL(V)$ such that the group structure is preserved. Doing so we can define a range of representations for different objects.

Now lets get to your spefcific problem:

By what you wrote in your post, it seems that $D$ should be a general representation (what we called $\Pi$) while both equation (1) and (3) define specific representations. Now there is one thing here that I find confusing: $D(L)$ is given spactime indices. Generally $V$ is any strange vectorspace we can come up with, this has nothing todo with minkowski space or more generally a lorentzian spacetime. As such $D(L)$ should carry a different type of abstract index.

Now to the relations between (1) - (3). (1) is a special case of (2). This is what is known as the fundamental representation. For matrix Lie groups this essentially amounts to asking, if we where to write down the group in terms of matrices, e.g. rotation matrices for SO(n), what vectorspace would it act on? This is normally a starting point as for the Lie groups that show up here this representation is normally what we use to actually define our group. E.g. for the Lorentz group we use the property $\Lambda^\top \eta \Lambda = \eta$, whith $\Lambda$ the fundamental representation of the Lorentz group. Now for (3) the Spinor rep. this is as you said a special case of (2) as well.  (Upto the fact that this is actually a rep of the universal cover instead). So (2) just captures the general notion of a representation with (1), (3) being specific examples that turn out to be useful.
Another typical example is the trivial representation that leaves the object invariant by the way, this is what allows us to define scalar fields i.e. maps

$\phi(x') = \phi(x)$

(where we ignore the sublety of this being a scalar field and not a scalar)

Now why would we introduce such objects? The canonical example for this is Spin! In nature we find particles of different intrinsic angular momentum, however if we look e.g. at quantum field theories it turns out that only using scalar fields and vector fields transforming in the fundamental representation we never find objects that have spin $1/2$. However in nature these show up as e.g. electrons. This spin is then found in the spinor representation you mentioned above.

Another example are gauge bosons which are responsible for the fundamental forces (except gravity) these turn out to transform in what is known as the adjoint representation. Generally the idea is that introducing representations on different vectorspaces gives us the opportunity to encode additional information e.g. the spin or charge of a particle/objects.

Now concering spinors of the galileo group, I have never actually thaught about that, however seeing that the group includes a SU(2) subgroup (as a double cover) it is likely that the representation is similar in the sense that the spinors would transform identically under rotations. However as the boots in both groups are different these probably act differntly (though very similar in structure). However as I've said, I've never actually worked with reps in this group. (You can find more information in Quantum Mechanics: A Modern Development by Ballentine)